# How to change view mode of view row using hook_views_pre_render?

Tags: views, 8, entities

Is it possible to change the view mode of a view result in `hook_views_pre_render`?

For example I have 3 different view modes (teaser, teaser-full, teaser-short). The goal is to have the view repeat these 3 teaser templates in the view page/listing, but I'm firstly struggling to change the view mode at all.

I tried the below, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
function themename_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
  foreach ($view->result as $index => $row) {
    $view->row_index = $index;
    $view->rowPlugin->options['view_mode'] = 'teaser';
  }
}
```

**Note**: If I drop a breakpoint into the code, it is being hit. But still gets rendered out as default view mode.

Comment: After adding the function, did you do a cache rebuild? If you drop a breakpoint into the code, is the code being hit?

Comment: @Kevin yes it is being hit, but still gets rendered out as default view mode.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to change the view mode in the hook_views_pre_execute() hook. I believe _views_pre_render() is too late.

```
function custom_module_views_pre_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
  // Some logic to determine view mode...

  $view->rowPlugin->options['view_mode'] = 'list';
}
```

Comment: We can change the field view mode like this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/290310/36948

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to get custom_module_views_pre_execute(ViewExecutable $view) example to work.

After inspecting with xdebug, I was able to use this:

```
function custom_module_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  /** @var \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view */
  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->id() == 'view_name' && $view->current_display == "display_name") {
    if (count($view->result) == 1) {
      // Change view mode to teaser when there is only 1 item.
      $variables['rows'][0]['#rows'][0]['#view_mode'] = 'teaser';
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Views Parity Row](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_parity_row) solves this problem. Worked well for my needs, I just wanted a different view mode for first row item so had to apply [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_parity_row/issues/2725115) for Drupal 8. Works well for other use cases.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using the Views UI:

1. Install [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module
2. Make Fields your format

   [image]
3. Since you have Entity API, you can add *Rendered Entity* as a field.

[image]

4. Select your view mode.

[image]

5. Add more render entity fields for your other view modes (repeat steps 3 and 4).